# Why is my brioche dry?

Tags: baking, bread, dough

Patient: Brioche. Dry like a croissant. Huge air bubbles.

- 120 g all purpose flour
- 96 g heavy cream
- 1 egg
- 10g yeast
- salt
- 10 g sugar

Mixed ingredients with lumps, 16h in the fridge, 5h in room temp, into the warm oven meanwhile.

So, how do you think, what did I do wrong?

Comment: How long did you bake it for, at what temperature, and how did you test it was done?

Comment: @MarkWildon no answers (including half-answers etc.) in comments, please.

Comment: well, TBH 220C-ish until brown. Like 10-15min.

Answer (score 2):

As per Stephie's comment, I'm adding this as an answer, even though it has to be largely conjectural.

10g of yeast is a lot of yeast for this amount of dough. With a five hour proof at room temperature, I think it is very likely that your dough is overproofed. This means the gluten structure over-develops and then becomes exhausted. So rather than a matrix of small bubbles you get a few big cavities in an otherwise heavy loaf.